# default route of br0 gets dev eth0 instead of dev br0

Tags: networking, bridge, network-interface, iproute

On my LinuxMint laptop, i have a recurring problem with my `bridge br0`.  On each start up, the default route does not work.  The routing table uses `eth0` instead of `br0` probably because of `dhcp`.  i roam with the laptop so turning off `dhcp` is not an option.  I need to access `VMs` at home, work, and on the road.  Bridges work with `dhcp`, but for some reason `eth0` is not behaving like a manual interface.

```
$ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
```

The internet is available as soon as:

```
$sudo ip route del default
$sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev br0
```

Why is it using the `dev eth0` when it needs to use `dev br0`?

In `/var/lib/NetworkManager/`, there is a dhclient lease file for `eth0`, but `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired Connection 1` has `method = manual`.

Comment: Is your dhcp client bound to `br0` or to `eth0`?

Comment: Maybe, but hard to answer that question.  Nice to have a script that interrogates the major dhcpc type daemons.   NetworkManager "appeared" to be disabled using its gui interface but its service was running.  Also had a gui for dhcpd called "Network Configurator 0.6.0" in the taskbar but it also said dhcpcd was not running.  The only thing that changed was that the kernel was updated and it might be working now, but will have to test more.