# What is and what creates br0 interface?

Tags: linux, network-interface

I'd like to know more about origin of `br0` as many tutorials refer to it but don't explain how does it come into existence.

Is it coming from some kernel module/driver? Is it always available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [default route of br0 gets dev eth0 instead of dev br0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178840/default-route-of-br0-gets-dev-eth0-instead-of-dev-br0) it's a network bridge device.

You set it up like you would a network interface.  Looking at the kernel source, it was started in 2001.

More information can be found at:

- [RedHat: NETWORK BRIDGE](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s2-networkscripts-interfaces_network-bridge)
- [Debian.org: Bridging Network Connections](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections)
- [kernel.googlesource.com: bridge-utils](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/shemminger/bridge-utils/)

Comment: brctl show  查看网桥状态